# error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Category]

Tags: apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Im getting error while converting rdd to DF()
error: value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Category]
Could anyone help me to sort out this please.

Comment: We need to know what have you tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to import sqlContext.implicits._